# Conditional tag affecting taxonomy term and its children?

Tags: taxonomy, conditional-content

I am wondering how can I write a conditional tag that affects a custom taxonomy slug and its children?

Found this in Wordpress Codex:

```
is_tax( 'flavor', 'mild')
```

> When the archive page for the flavor
>   taxonomy with the slug of 'mild' is
>   being displayed.

However with this code only 'mild' slug archive page is affected and not it's children taxonomy terms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a handy little function that i based on [post_is_in_descendant_category function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category)
it expends the is_tax to check if its the term or any of his children

```
function is_or_descendant_tax( $terms,$taxonomy){
    if (is_tax($taxonomy, $terms)){
            return true;
    }
    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
        $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $term, $taxonomy);
        if ( $descendants && is_tax($taxonomy, $descendants) )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and you use it just the same so instead of:

`is_tax('flavor', 'mild');`

you put:

`is_or_descendant_tax(get_term_by( 'name', 'mild', 'flavor' ), 'flavor');`

or if you are using term id instead of name then:

`is_or_descendant_tax(12, 'flavor');`

and you are set.